# Webpack-dev-server shows jade files as text on the localhost?

Tags: node.js, webpack-dev-server

I've downloaded Webpack-dev-server as a dev dependency. Everything works fine, but when I navigate to the index.jade file on the localhost, it shows the actual jade code as text? I'm doing something really obvious and stupid probably, please help.

thank you

Comment: You need the jade loader.

Comment: But I have that in my express view engine?

Comment: Well then , you need to proxy to your node server for that part https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy

Comment: ok, I really don't understand that link, but I'll try teach myself like I've been doing all this time anyways haha. btw I just tried adding the pug-html-loader and now when I click the index.pug file on the localhost of the webpack-dev-server, it downloads the file?